# Memory Utilization Pattern Solidity?

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, contract-development, contract-design, remix

I was wondering what is the most efficient way (and why), to use variables in memory for function calls with regards to A and B?

**A)** Like this:

```
 function checkBalance() public view returns (uint256) {
        address _payee = msg.sender;
        return balanceOf(_payee);
    }
```

**B)** Or like this:

```
     function checkBalance(address beneficiary) public view returns (uint256) {
            return balanceOf(beneficiary);
        }
```

Comment: It is unclear what the `modifier` have to do with the question.

Comment: I removed it, you're correct.

Comment: Those functions are not the same: a) it returns the sender balance, b) it returns the balance of any address so it is hard to compare. You have to take into consideration other things like that using a lot of local variables might cause the error message "stack too deep".

Comment: But in A, why would one want to create a local variable to save msg.sender? why not just return msg.sender and remove the payee variable? are the situations where the above pattern is recommended?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So if you mean if there is a serious penalty for instantiating a variable in memory rather than using it directly, no, there's not. Actually probably there will be no penalty at all if the compiler is smart enough, which shouldn't be a problem in cases like this one (specially with optimization enabled in the solidity compiler).

That being said, I'd only store a variable in a local one for the sake or readability, which is in my opinion not justified in your case, so `B` would be preferred for both simplicity and readability, but I guess it's a matter of taste.